# VBA script when dividing by zero

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to do a formula in VBA, but I am coming across errors because of a zero in the denominator.  If I have a zero in the denominator, I'd like the active cell to be set to zero.  Whatever I am doing is incorrect, and I am not a programmer.  I have no idea what I'm doing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what I

```
Range("H" & Row).Activate
If Range("F" & Row) = 0 Then ActiveCell.Formula = 0
ActiveCell.Formula = Range("G" & Row) / Range("F" & Row)
```

Answer (score 3):

try using an else

something like

```
Range("H" & Row).Activate
If Range("F" & Row) = 0 Then
    ActiveCell.Formula = 0
Else 
    ActiveCell.Formula = Range("G" & Row) / Range("F" & Row)
End If
```

Comment: @JackPrible add a new line after "Then" and "Else" and after the last line add "End If" (or rather than these changes, add " _" after the end of the line with Then on it, and a colon ":" after Else)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.  I figured out where I was going wrong.  I'm taking from a source and filling a new spreadsheet.  I was using Row instead of InsertPos.

Answer (score 0):

You could just build the statement into the formula:

```
For Row = 1 To 3
    Cells(Row, "H").Formula = "=IF(F" & Row & "=0,0,G" & Row & "/F" & Row & ")"
Next Row
```

And instead of using a loop...

```
With Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IF(F" & .Row & "=0,0,G" & .Row & "/F" & .Row & ")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: I am not very good with coding.  In the first suggestion you made, at what point do I put my formula in?

Comment: @JackPrible what tigeravatar's answer is saying is why not just use a normal Excel formula (as generated by VBA if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend Cor_Blimey or tigeravatar recommend - both make the code less readable. Cor_Blimey's suggestion to use the line continuation character " _" and the end of statement character  ":" do not add to the succinctness of the code and is logically the same as the code above. Tigeravatar is sortof on the right track with suggesting that the cell handle the error case itself, but his  code suggestion makes everything more difficult to read.

My suggested change is to drop the VBA entirely and use the following formula in the  cell(s) in column H that would be  doing the calculations:

```
=IfError(G1/F1,0)
```

This would work because you are not using any values in your calculations other than what  is already on the worksheet.